# How to get sub catgory and sub sub category in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i need sub category in first dropdown and sub sub category in second drop down
like :

-Album
-single track

and second dropdown

-- new songs
-- new single track

plz help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this code : http://bilalhssn.blogspot.in/2015/11/how-to-get-products-on-category-hover.html

Hope this exactly what you want to do :)